# How to correctly extract the regression equation from `stat_smooth` or a regression model in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I plot the equation extracted from `stat_smooth`, but it mismatches the origin one.

I tried draw a regression line with `stat_smooth`, and again draw the formula of regression use `stat_function`, but the 2 curves are obviously different. What I did wrong?

I can't post pictures yet, so I provide an example with `ggpmisc` package:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point() +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_line(formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 2)) +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(aes(label = after_stat(eq.label)), 
                        formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 2))
```

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point() +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_line(formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 2)) +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(aes(label = after_stat(eq.label)), 
                        formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 2)) +
  stat_function(fun = \(x) 231 - 585 * x + 190 * x ^ 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `x` value is transformed into an orthogonal polynomial when you use `poly(x, 2)`.

When you use `x` in `stat_function`, your `x` value is the original `x` values and not your polynomial `x` values.

Here's a workaround:

```
# Compute your polynomial a priori
polynomial <- poly(mtcars$mpg, 2)

# Compute your equation using the polynomials
mtcars$newY <- 231 - 585 * polynomial[,"1"] + 190 * polynomial[,"2"]

# Plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point() +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_line(formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 2)) +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(aes(label = after_stat(eq.label)), 
                        formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 2)) +
  geom_line(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = newY))
```